# Persistant Service Workers and caching HTML and PNG files

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to make Service Workers persistent, and also how I would cache HTML and PNG files. I want to be able to browse my webpage offline after being online. The JavaScript files that I do cache get removed once I go to another page.

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find a straight answer. Also, everytime I try to cache the HTML and PNG files, I does, but it throws an error and like the JavaScript files it just disappears after you change the page.

This is the raw code: [github.com/VirxEC/CalcPlus/tree/master/docs](https://github.com/VirxEC/CalcPlus/tree/master/docs)

This is the site: [virxec.github.io/CalcPlus](https://virxec.github.io/CalcPlus)

You can toggle the Service Workers here (click "Offline Mode"): https://virxec.github.io/CalcPlus/PageOptions.html

My code is in PageOptions to enable service workers (starting on line 91):

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/PreviewLibrary.html");
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/LibrarySource.html");
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/AboutLibrary.html");
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/PageOptions.html");
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/index.html");        
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/assets/Library.js");
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/assets/logo.png");

navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
    console.log('Service worker successfully registered on scope', registration.scope);
});
```

I expect no errors to be thrown, and I won't want the Service Workers to disappear after you go to some other page. I want them to say, so you can just load them and then browse the site offline after that.

Comment: @CodeF0x I added the code, sorry

Comment: Didn't want to appear mean. It's just because the question will be useless if those third party links go down ;). Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very old, and I have since found the solution for it and forgotten about this question I asked. Here is the solution for caching any file in the service worker.

In `index.html`, have this code to register the service worker:

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js");
} else {
    console.warn("serviceWorker isn't in navigator");
}
```

Then, in `service-worker.js`:

```js
const version = "v1";
const urls = [
    "/index.html", // these are all example URLs
    "/logo.png",
    "/my-script.js",
    "/LICENSE"
];

self.addEventListener("install", e => e.waitUntil(caches.open(version).then(f => f.addAll(urls)).then(() => self.skipWaiting())));
self.addEventListener("activate", g => g.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(c => Promise.all(c.map(i => i != c ? caches.delete(i) : null)))));
self.addEventListener("fetch", j => j.request.mode != 'navigate' ? 0 : j.respondWith(fetch(j.request).catch(() => caches.match(j.request))));
```

When the user then visits the index, the server worker cache any file.